# How do I reset numbering in tables?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have some data that I have been working with. With that, I have been deleting records on-the-fly. Now that I have a working data model, I want to re-start my auto-numbering. How do I reset my existing data to adhere to an auto-formatting starting from 1....n?

I have tried to do a `Compact and Repair` but that didn't seem to fix the issue.

For reference, my table looks like this:

```
R-002
R-054
R-123
R-057
R-061
```

I would like to get them back to:

```
   R-001
   R-002
   R-003
   R-004
   R-005
```

And for each subsequent entry added, adhere to this new auto-numbering so the next record, for example, will be `R-006`.

Writing an `UPDATE` query works for immediate fixing but it doesn't address the adherence to the auto-numbering for future entries.

I would think there is an elegant way to do this. The data in my tables are part of `Relationships` so it makes it a little tricky.

If anyone has any tips / recommendations, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I would advise against it: If those numbers have any meaning (or are shown in the user interface), you should not use auto-numbers, because you *will* get new gaps in the future. If they don't have any meaning and are not shown in the user interface, you should not care whether they have gaps or not.

Comment: They are displayed in the UI so that's the issue I am dealing with.

Comment: Compact and Repair will reset the Autonumber to <current maximum + 1>. To restart at 1, you must delete all records. There is no automatic way to update all numbers as you intend.

Comment: Would making an update query to reset the numbers, and then on After Update, get the last element in the table and then increment it by 1 for the new value?

Comment: @Darnold14: If they are displayed in the UI, the recommended approach is *not* to use auto-numbers but to do the incrementing yourself. That way, you have full control over these numbers.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is *sequential numbering* of the records.

I wrote an article on the various methods for doing this:
[Sequential Rows in Microsoft Access](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33069/Sequential-Rows-in-Microsoft-Access.html)

One is to add *row numbers*:

```vb
' Builds consecutive row numbers in a select, append, or create query
' with the option of a initial automatic reset.
' Optionally, a grouping key can be passed to reset the row count
' for every group key.
'
' 2018-08-23. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function RowNumber( _
    ByVal Key As String, _
    Optional ByVal GroupKey As String, _
    Optional ByVal Reset As Boolean) _
    As Long

    ' Uncommon character string to assemble GroupKey and Key as a compound key.
    Const KeySeparator      As String = "¤§¤"
    ' Expected error codes to accept.
    Const CannotAddKey      As Long = 457
    Const CannotRemoveKey   As Long = 5

    Static Keys             As New Collection
    Static GroupKeys        As New Collection
    Dim Count               As Long
    Dim CompoundKey         As String

    On Error GoTo Err_RowNumber

    If Reset = True Then
        ' Erase the collection of keys and group key counts.
        Set Keys = Nothing
        Set GroupKeys = Nothing
    Else
        ' Create a compound key to uniquely identify GroupKey and its Key.
        ' Note: If GroupKey is not used, only one element will be added.
        CompoundKey = GroupKey & KeySeparator & Key
        Count = Keys(CompoundKey)

        If Count = 0 Then
            ' This record has not been enumerated.
            '
            ' Will either fail if the group key is new, leaving Count as zero,
            ' or retrieve the count of already enumerated records with this group key.
            Count = GroupKeys(GroupKey) + 1
            If Count > 0 Then
                ' The group key has been recorded.
                ' Remove it to allow it to be recreated holding the new count.
                GroupKeys.Remove (GroupKey)
            Else
                ' This record is the first having this group key.
                ' Thus, the count is 1.
                Count = 1
            End If
            ' (Re)create the group key item with the value of the count of keys.
            GroupKeys.Add Count, GroupKey
        End If
        ' Add the key and its enumeration.
        ' This will be:
        '   Using no group key: Relative to the full recordset.
        '   Using a group key:  Relative to the group key.
        ' Will fail if the key already has been created.
        Keys.Add Count, CompoundKey
    End If

    ' Return the key value as this is the row counter.
    RowNumber = Count

Exit_RowNumber:
    Exit Function

Err_RowNumber:
    Select Case Err
        Case CannotAddKey
            ' Key is present, thus cannot be added again.
            Resume Next
        Case CannotRemoveKey
            ' GroupKey is not present, thus cannot be removed.
            Resume Next
        Case Else
            ' Some other error. Ignore.
            Resume Exit_RowNumber
    End Select
End Function
```

These you could format as you like, for example:

```
RNumber: "R-" & Format([RwoNumber], "000")
```

Comment: Interesting. What event would fire this method, however?

Comment: None. The intended usage is an a query.

Comment: I appreciate the response - could you demonstrate how it would look in a query with a referenced table?

Comment: Not sure what a referenced table could be in this context ... but study the article linked and its attached full demo.